# EOF error when reading dict from file

Tags: python

I have a .txt file that contains a dict in the following format:

```
{
 "key1": "value1",
 "key2": "value2",
}
```

I'm trying to read this into a variable so I can use it.  I can do so with something like:

```
    f = open('my_dict.txt', 'r')
    my_dict = eval(f.read())
```

But if I try to use the below, Python complains about an unexpected EOF after the first "{".

```
dict_from_file = []
with open('my_dict.txt', 'r') as inf:
        for line in inf:
            dict_from_file.append(eval(line))
print(dict_from_file)


     { 
     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I'm sure it just has to do with everything formatted line by line in the file.  I guess I could reformat the file so that newlines are replaced with ",", but I like having the readability of every key:value pair on a line.  I'd like to be able to use `with`.  How can I go about doing that?

Comment: try with `f.read().strip()`. And i would replace `eval()` with `ast.literal_eval()` from `ast`

Comment: Why are you trying to use Python's string representation instead of a proper interchange format like JSON?

Comment: Where did the `.txt` file come from? Assuming it is generated by code then use the `json` or `pickle` modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can not directly `eval('{')`, it will raise the error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Append them to a string `'{"key1": "value1","key2": "value2",}'`, then `eval` it, that's same as your code  `my_dict = eval(f.read())`

Try this:

```
dict_from_file = ''
with open('my_dict.txt', 'r') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        dict_from_file= dict_from_file+(line.strip())
print eval(dict_from_file)
```

Output:

```
{'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

Comment: The problem is that `dict_from_file` is still a `str`.  I need it's final form to actually be a dict.

Comment: `eval(dict_from_file)` is a dict, you can assign it to any variable you want.

Comment: Ahh I see what you are saying!  The only thing I had to change was the print statement to `print(eval(dict_from_file))` since I'm on Python 3+.  I'll award you the answer!

Answer (score 1):

According to This [json specification](http://www.json.org/), this is a malformed JSON file with a trailing comma.

A proper json file can be easily read into dict using json module

```
import json 
with open('my_dict.txt') as f:
  my_json = json.loads(f)
```

Comment: Yes, I started playing around with JSON after I couldn't get what I wanted figured out.  It appears what you wrote works as I just coded the same thing as you typed this.